# Discrete Mathematics - Combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics

How many strings with three digits from $0,1,\dots,9$, and three letters from A, B, C, D, E can be
formed, if they begin with a letter and no letter can be used
with more than once?

For example CD2A09, D07B0E, ABC444 are allowed but not 123ABC or B30A4B.

I thought like multinomial theorem $6!/(3!\cdot 3!)$ but I was wrong.

How can I solve it?

Comment: What three numbers??? And what do you possibly mean by "begin with a letter, no letter, our more than once"????? This question needs some serious rephrasing!

Comment: Can be any number i think?

Comment: @JonasBo it still isn't clear what can I use where. I understand the letter must be one of ABCDE, but what sequences are illegal? I can't use repeated letters, is that it? Other than the first character, that must be a letter, can I order the other things as I wish?

Comment: if it is to begin with a letter and no letter, can be
with more than once

Comment: Like this CD2A09, D07B0E, ABC444, but not 123ABC
or B30A4B

Comment: @Jonas Bo I am not sure if I have understood correctly the statement of your problem. What is the proposed answer?

Comment: You have right answer Robert Z!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $5$ ways for the letter in the first position, then we choose two positions among the remaining 5 for the other two letters in $\binom{5}{2}$ ways, we pick the two distinct letters (in order) among the remaining 4 in $4\cdot 3$ ways, and finally we take the 3 numbers among $0,1,\dots,9$ in $10^3$ ways (here repetitions are allowed).

Hence the answer is $5\cdot \binom{5}{2}\cdot (4\cdot 3) \cdot 10^3=600000$.

Comment: RobertZ where does 4 times 3 come from?

Comment: Jonas Bo The ways you have to choose the second and the third letter.

Comment: And why does it becomes 10^(3) RobertZ

Comment: @Jonas Bo You 10 ways to choose the first digit, 10 for the second and 10 for the third.